# Should I switch from Google Sign-In to Firebase auth

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am currently reworking an app that was created in 2017 which uses Google Sign-In for unity to let users sign in and get the users name and profile pic. The app also uses Firebase analytics and Crashlytics now.

I have been having some issues with Google Sign-In and while looking at it noticed that it has not been updated on GitHub for 3+ years.

I was wondering, should I stay with Google Sign-In or try moving to Firebase Auth. Am I completely misunderstanding the point of FirebaseAuth?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely change to Firebase.  Firebase includes, as you say, authorization.

Authorization is incredibly difficult and time-consuming as you know, but, Firebase makes it as easy as possible.  It's not perfect but it's the easiest way.

Indeed, many projects actually use Firebase, for the one and only reason of using the authorization built-in to Firebase .. they don't even bother using Firebase (data, sync, etc) as such.

GoogleSignIn is crap, just delete it.